Double sharp on B major key signature
I am starting to playing a piano piece by Mussorgsky, Il Vecchio Castello, and I found this:

So do I need to elevate the F# by a tone hence becoming G#?

If an accidental such as that double-sharp had to be added to the existing sharp in the key signature, wouldn't a natural have to be added to the existing accidental — and thus never have any effect?

The indicated pitch is F-double-sharp, so you should play the G key.  The double sharp isn't added to the existing sharp, so it is only a half step higher than the unaltered pitch, not a whole step.
